# Sharepoint server web analytics does not work

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, web-analytics

I have a sharepoint 2010 server which is not showing the web analytics details for quite some time. It was working perfect previously.

Message

There is no data available for this report. Here are some possible reasons: (1) Web Analytics has not been enabled long enough to generate data; (2) There is insufficient data to generate this report; (3) Data logging required for this report might not be enabled; (4) Data aggregation might not be enabled at the level required for this report.

I have checked all the possible forum answers. (running sps,  restarting services, checking the web analytics configuration and logs). No luck yet. I can still see the .usage file in the log folders with some good amt of data. I have checked the reporting db,staging db data and  I can see some latest timestamped data in that. Not sure of  the problem here.

The only notificable change i did was " changed the log location to some other drive folder few months ago. ". I reverted the log location to default ( 14 hive logs) now. But still not working.

I happened to see a below message in the event log.

The Execute method of job definition Microsoft.Office.Server.WebAnalytics.WebAnalyticsWorkflowTriggerJobDefinition (ID 14170976-fa4b-4efd-8ac1-3232a4e33147) threw an exception. More information is included below.
0x80070003

Note: Seems this error code is for "Directory Not found" issue.

ULS Log

04/17/2012 05:25:33.87  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x3ABC)                    0x34AC SharePoint Foundation          General                        88z7 Medium   SPRequest: Logging result 0x360b9180 from reInit 91d5a3f7-ed3e-44e5-811c-ff27253b1e08
04/17/2012 05:25:33.87  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x3ABC)                    0x34AC SharePoint Foundation          General                        8e2s Medium   Unknown SPRequest error occurred. More information: 0x80070003 91d5a3f7-ed3e-44e5-811c-ff27253b1e08
04/17/2012 05:25:33.87  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x3ABC)                    0x34AC SharePoint Foundation          General                        72k4 Medium   0x80070003 91d5a3f7-ed3e-44e5-811c-ff27253b1e08
04/17/2012 05:25:33.87  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x3ABC)                    0x34AC SharePoint Foundation          General                        8kh7 High     0x80070003 91d5a3f7-ed3e-44e5-811c-ff27253b1e08
04/17/2012 05:25:33.98  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x3ABC)                    0x34AC SharePoint Foundation          Timer                          6398 Critical The Execute method of job definition Microsoft.Office.Server.WebAnalytics.WebAnalyticsWorkflowTriggerJobDefinition (ID 14170976-fa4b-4efd-8ac1-3232a4e33147) threw an exception. More information is included below.  0x80070003 91d5a3f7-ed3e-44e5-811c-ff27253b1e08
04/17/2012 05:25:34.04  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x3ABC)                    0x3424 SharePoint Foundation          Monitoring                     nasq Medium   Entering monitored scope (Timer Job job-immediate-alerts) ad723ab2-aad6-4b58-90cf-dc05ddc68f78
04/17/2012 05:25:34.07  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x3ABC)                    0x3424 SharePoint Foundation          Monitoring                     b4ly Medium   Leaving Monitored Scope (Timer Job job-immediate-alerts). Execution Time=29.2460986852286 ad723ab2-aad6-4b58-90cf-dc05ddc68f78
04/17/2012 05:25:34.09  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x3ABC)                    0x3424 SharePoint Foundation          Monitoring                     nasq Medium   Entering monitored scope (Timer Job job-immediate-alerts) ad723ab2-aad6-4b58-90cf-dc05ddc68f78
04/17/2012 05:25:34.10  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x3ABC)                    0x3424 SharePoint Foundation          Monitoring                     b4ly Medium   Leaving Monitored Scope (Timer Job job-immediate-alerts). Execution Time=15.6091086239671 ad723ab2-aad6-4b58-90cf-dc05ddc68f78
04/17/2012 05:25:34.26  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x3ABC)                    0x34AC SharePoint Foundation          Timer                          72ae Unexpected Exception stack trace:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetAllWebsOfSite(String bstrUrl, Object& pvarWebs, Object& pvarWebIds, Object& pvarParentWebs, Object& pvarLangs, Object& pvarTitles, Object& pvarUIVersions, Object& pvarFlags, Object& pvarWebTemplates, Object& pvarConfigurations, Object& pvarMasterUrls, Object& pvarCustomMasterUrls)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetAllWebsOfSite(String bstrUrl, Object& pvarWebs, Object& pvarWebIds, Object& pvarParentWebs, Object& pvarLangs, Object& pvarTitles, Object& pvarUIVersions, Object& pvarFlags, Object& pvarWebTemplates, Object& pvarConfigurations, Object& pvarMasterUrls, Object& pvarCustomMasterUrls)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.SPWebCollectionProvider.GetWebsData(String[]& strNames, String[]& st... 91d5a3f7-ed3e-44e5-811c-ff27253b1e08
04/17/2012 05:25:34.26* OWSTIMER.EXE (0x3ABC)                    0x34AC SharePoint Foundation          Timer                          72ae Unexpected ...rServiceRelUrls, Guid[]& guidWebIds, Int32[]& nLanguages, String[]& strTitles, String[]& strDescriptions, String[]& strCreationTimes, String[]& strModifiedTimes, Boolean[]& bUserIsWebAdmins, Int32[]& nWebTemplates, Int16[]& nProvisionConfigs, Int16[]& nMeetingCounts, Int32[]& nUIVersions, Int32[]& nFlags, String[]& strMasterUrls, String[]& strCustomMasterUrls)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWebCollection.EnsureWebsData()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPBaseCollection.GetEnumerator()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.WebAnalytics.WebAnalyticsWorkflowTriggerJobDefinition.ProcessSite(SPSite siteToProcess, SPJobState jobState)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAllSitesJobDefinition.Execute(SPContentDatabase contentDatabase, SPJobState jobState)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.WebAnalytics.... 91d5a3f7-ed3e-44e5-811c-ff27253b1e08
04/17/2012 05:25:34.26* OWSTIMER.EXE (0x3ABC)                    0x34AC SharePoint Foundation          Timer                          72ae Unexpected ...WebAnalyticsWorkflowTriggerJobDefinition.Execute(SPContentDatabase contentDatabase, SPJobState jobState)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPContentDatabaseJobDefinition.Execute(SPJobState jobState)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPTimerJobInvokeInternal.Invoke(SPJobDefinition jd, Guid targetInstanceId, Boolean isTimerService, Int32& result) 91d5a3f7-ed3e-44e5-811c-ff27253b1e08
04/17/2012 05:25:34.26  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x3ABC)                    0x34AC SharePoint Foundation          Monitoring                     b4ly Medium   Leaving Monitored Scope (Timer Job WebAn

Am fine to create the new service application on the worst case. But not sure whether i will miss my old data or not.  If anybody has any experience in this issue kindly share it with me.

Answer (score 1):

There is basic things you could do, such as restart the server and even there is troubles, recreate the web analytics services.

Last operation step would be to run the SharePoint Configuration Wizard to be sure that everything is in order.

Comment: Will recreating the service app result in losing the historical log data? The server used has some important user information used for statistical analysis on usage patterns.

Comment: I never test it, so be careful with what i'd say. In my view, you could  recreate the service using the same databases, so normally the databases will remains the same. Can you experiment this on a test farm?